# How to pass values from one controller to another controller

Tags: angularjs

I have

1.) Controller1.js ( which has an array named Arr )

2.) Controller2.js

How should I pass **Arr** from Controller1.js to Controller2.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it, best practice is to create service and store the value in it, and then inject it to both controllers. The angular service is singleton. You can read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) about services.

Second (and not good) way is to use $rootScope.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myController1', ['myService', function (myService) {
  //myService.array

}])
.controller('myController2', ['myService', function (myService) {
  //myService.array

}])
.service('myService', [function () {
  var service = {};
  service.array = [];

  return service
}])
```

Comment: I modified the answer. But best way is to read angular documentation.